# How does solution which electrodes are immersed in effect electrode potential?

Tags: electrochemistry

When we make an electrochemical cell, we dip the electrodes in the salt solution. How exactly does the electrode potential change as we dip the electrodes in the salt solutions?  Would different salt solutions change the effect of the electrode potential?

Comment: There is no electrode potential if the electrode is not dipped in the salt solution

Comment: @Maurice There is an electrode potential of not dipped in electrode, but in electrostatic sense, not electrochemical sense.

Comment: @ Poutnik. Right. There is an electrostatic potential. But this potential is constantly fluctuating, changing if you approach your hand or any other capacity effect.

Comment: @Maurice Surely it does. I remember an old, vacuum tube based pH meter in early 80s at a high school lab, where you had to stay 2 meters away and being still while reading pH value. The glass electrode and pH meter input had probably so high impedance it was like not being connected at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that we want a cathodic reaction so we can use the metals with a positive standard reduction potential (because 0 is for $\ce{H2} $ reduction).

In reality however to really find a suitable electrolyte cyclic voltammetry is typically used and electrolytes with suitable electrochemical windows for the cell reaction are chosen.

[image]
The electrochemical window is the voltages where the current is zero in the picture above. If the wrong electrolyte is chosen then a full redox reaction happens(with the electrolyte participating) rather than half reactions at each electrode negating the need for the external circuit and creating heat

Comment: what is this? electrolyte cyclic voltammetry
 and if current is there that means transfer of ions hence redox right?

Comment: We know that*Nernst eqn $$ \Delta G=-nFE $$ so a spontaneous reaction occurs at negative gibbs free energy or positive cell potentials(E). The cell potential can be calculated using a standard reduction table Ecell=Eoxidation+ Ereduction. With water hydrogen ions are reduced at zero volts so if a metal with a +ve oxidation potential (aka a metal with a negative reduction potential) were in the presence of water it would be oxidized and hydrogen ion would be reduced (+ve Ecell). So with WATER we use positive reduction potentials but with other electrolytes it depends on its reduction potentials